# Not able to run on android, while iOS runs fine

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-android

I am pretty new to react-native development, I have a project which run properly with iOS simulator, while on android (Emulator and device) it gives **Unexpected token '>' error**
[image]

Comment: check the error in node  terminal... and provide that error

Comment: I was searching this error, and somewhere a error resembling i found was due to react-native-facebook-login npm package used in project.. ??? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change "android" folder name to "android-backup"

And run following in the terminal:

```
$cd MyProjectFolder
$npm start
$react-native start
```

this work refresh your android project.

also you can clean gradlew with:

```
$cd android
$gradlew clean
```

Comment: did many a times- not working.
also did react-native update after deleting android module.

Comment: you can see file and line number of error in error massage. Or in details. Please see and get the line that have error.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

*Open Terminal*

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

react-native run-android
```

Comment: tried, didn't work. its some kind of jsx syntax error, but the thing is for iOS it runs fine, I have also checked every Platform.OS condition. TY